# Updating Login Status in Site.Master

Tags: asp.net, session

I am working on web application. 
In this application user need to login to perform some task. I have made my custom login screen. I want to make the login status of site.master to get updated as soon as user logs in but to be frank, i don't know how to do it.

The code below is taken from the login.aspx.cs. When user click login button following code will be executed. But i don't know i can i update the login status in site.master(Picture Included)

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string user = username.Text;
            string pass = password.Text;
            Session["firstName"] = username.Text;
            localhost.UserRegistration n = new localhost.UserRegistration();


            if (n.checkUser(user, pass))
            {
                Response.Redirect("UserProfile.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                message1.Text = "UserName or Password is Wrong. Please check your details and login again.";
            }
```

Please [Click Here](http://i49.tinypic.com/33zelqq.jpg) to look the Picture so someone might have idea on it.

Site.Master Code

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="SystemSoftware.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="~/Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
    <div class="page">
        <div class="header">
            <div class="title">
                <h1>
                    My ASP.NET Application
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="loginDisplay">
                <asp:LoginView ID="HeadLoginView" runat="server" EnableViewState="false">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        [ <a href="~/Login.aspx" ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server">Log In</a> ]
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        Welcome <span class="bold"><asp:LoginName ID="HeadLoginName" runat="server" /></span>!
                        [ <asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/"/> ]
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
            <div class="clear hideSkiplink">
                <asp:Menu ID="NavigationMenu" runat="server" CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="false" IncludeStyleBlock="false" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Items>

                        <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Create Account.aspx" Text="Create Account"/>


                    </Items>
                </asp:Menu>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server"/>
        </div>
        <div class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Site.Master.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace SystemSoftware
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["firstName"] != null)
            {
                HeadLoginView.Visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                HeadLoginView.Visible = true;

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In you masterpage load event check for session that you are creating when user is logged in . If that session is not empty show logout link else keep that link login . In your master aspx add 2 links 1 for login one for logout.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (Session["Username"]!=null && Session["Username"]!=String.Empty)
            {
               lnkLogin.visible = false;
               lnkLogout.visible = true;
            }else{
               lnkLogin.visible = true;
               lnkLogout.visible = false;
            }
}
```

Comment: if(Session["firstName"] != null)

Comment: How can i add link for login and log out

Comment: You have not posted your masterpage aspx code so its not possible to see what exactly you are doing .

Comment: Hi Sonesh I have posted the masterpage aspx code. Can you please find me solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can also change the properties of controls on master page from local page also like

String a = ((LinkButton)Master.FindControl("LinkLogIn")).Text

in the same manner you can modify any other property too

Comment: Lets say Website might have other 100 pages . User has to add this code on every single page to show logout link on masterpage.

Comment: then ,you will have to do changes on master page only I know ,I was not countering you answer.

Comment: No problem bud just a thought .